Replace text with markdown export artefacts of inline code blocks
I need to replace text like this:
\`**fooBar**\`

with text like this:
`fooBar`

How can I do so?

Context: Source of text was an "export to markdown" from a document, which resulted in this peculiar pattern.

In a text editor supporting regex "find-and-replace" feature...
Find with this regex:
\\`\*\*(\w+)\*\*\\`

Replace with this pattern:
`$1`


Explanation:
\ and * --> needs to be escaped in regex
`       --> no need to escape in regex
( and ) --> creates a capture group

The $1 references the capture group in the replacement text.
